# Preloading World Anchors Using Vuforia Engine & Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia, arcore, android-augmented-reality

When content is placed within an AR scene, an anchor stage is created. How can I preload an AR scene with an anchor stage already loaded into the scene, complete with content placed within it?

For example, how could I place a 3D Cube in the centre of the AR scene. Bearing in mind that the 3D Cube should remain at it's anchor point even when the device's position changes, just as a manually placed anchor stage would.

Comment: Is this assuming the AR scene has been loaded atleast once at that location before? Or does it need to preload this stage at any arbitrary location?

Comment: The stage will have been previously created within the AR scene. I currently capture the devices lat/long and the stage's screen position/rotation/scale at the moment where the content is placed.

Comment: What about putting your Object into a *Layer* that is deactivated in the *Culling Mask* of the camera? That way you can load what you want at anytime and display the content only when you need it.